# In a 2D project, I want to set the player movement when the player is in the same position as any object or not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a copy of a game called "Crazy Arcade.". In a 2D project.

If the player is in the same position as the water balloon and goes out of the water balloon, I want to prevent him from entering the water balloon again. So I used the code like "this". But this method is difficult to use if there are two players. If two players are in the same position as the water balloon, and one player goes out of the water balloon, the other player bounces off.

In the image, the 1p player is on the water balloon and the 2p player is trying to come up from outside the water balloon, but it can't come up on the water balloon.
If the 1p player and the 2p player are in the same position before the water balloon is installed, they can be on the water balloon at the same time and if the 2p player goes out of the water balloon, the 2p player cannot come back up on the water balloon, but the 1p player can continue to stay on the water balloon. And if 1p player goes out of the water balloon, 1p player can't come back up on the water balloon either.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

"this"

```
type here

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        collider.isTrigger = true;
    }
   }
   void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
   {
       if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
       {
           collider.isTrigger = false;
       }
   }
```

So another method that I used was to use Ray to stop the player's movement when the water balloon is recognized, but the player didn't stop.

```
type here

void Ray()
   {
       if(moveVec.x == 0 && moveVec.y == 1)
       {
           PlusVec = new Vector2(0, 0.2f);
           dirVec = Vector2.up;
       } else if(moveVec.x == 0 && moveVec.y == -1)
       {
           PlusVec = new Vector2(0, -0.4f);
           dirVec = Vector2.down;
       } else if(moveVec.x == -1 && moveVec.y == 0)
       {
           PlusVec = new Vector2(-0.3f, 0);
           dirVec = Vector2.left;
       } else if (moveVec.x == 1 && moveVec.y == 0)
       {
           PlusVec = new Vector2(0.3f, 0);
           dirVec = Vector2.right;
        }

        // Ray
        Debug.DrawRay(rigid.position + PlusVec, dirVec * 0.4f, new Color(0, 1, 0));
        RaycastHit2D rayHit = Physics2D.Raycast(rigid.position + PlusVec, dirVec, 0.4f,      LayerMask.GetMask("Balloon"));

           if (rayHit.collider != null)
           {
               scanObject = rayHit.collider.gameObject;
               rigid.velocity = Vector3.zero;
               Debug.Log(scanObject.name);
           }
           else
           {
               scanObject = null;

           }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I'm not sure that a physics-based solution fits for such kind of task. You can try to change layers to make sure that collisions will be ignored or not. However, it will need a ton of additional layers for every player and object. So it is not a good option in my mind in the case of many simultaneous players.

I would suggest moving your logic to the pure math layer. Then you will be able to restrict any non-needed movement before applying in the view.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem